# Kubernetes for i386 - Can't find binaries, can't compile (compile errors)

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, compilation, 32-bit, i386

Hi everyone and thank you for your time! ^_^

I'm currently building a cluster with a small 64bit computer and some 32bit laptops. The 64 bit works fine with kubernetes, but I cannot install/compile kubernetes on the 32 bit machines.

**64 bit machine:** *i3 - 8GB ram - 512GB SSD & 3TB HDD - CentOS 8 64bit
(everything installed and updated: git, docker, kubernetes, etc. and working).*

**32 bit machines:** *Atom/P4 - 1-4GB ram - 256GB SSD (& 1TB HDD) - Centos 7 32bit//Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 32bit.
(git, make, (even) go-lang, docker 32bit <-- All working. But...)*

Things tried:

- Searched for 32bit binaries for kubernetes, found only 'kubectl'.
- Tried compiling (new at this), 'make release', 'make 386', 'make i386', 'make linux-386' - It doesn't matter what I do, none of them work.
- Lot's of google searches, stack overflow, github bugs, and checking with people.
- Reading documentation.

These are the results of my last try (text (so you can copy/paste) & picture (so it would have format and syntax):

```
root@web3:/var/tmp/test1/kubernetes# build/run.sh make linux/386
 +++ [1221 12:37:58] Verifying Prerequisites....
 +++ [1221 12:37:59] Building Docker image kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1
 +++ Docker build command failed for kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1

 Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.75kB Step 1/16 : FROM
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-cross:v1.13.4-1  ---> cb825830a0c3 Step 2/16 : RUN
 touch /kube-build-image  ---> Running in 3a6491869df9
 standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format
 error" The command '/bin/sh -c touch /kube-build-image' returned a
 non-zero code: 1

 To retry manually, run:

 docker build -t kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1 --pull=false
 /var/tmp/test1/kubernetes/_output/images/kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1

 !!! [1221 12:38:03] Call tree: !!! [1221 12:38:03]  1: build/run.sh:31
 kube::build::build_image(...) !!! Error in
 build/../build/common.sh:431   Error in build/../build/common.sh:431.
 '((i<3-1))' exited with status 1 Call stack:   1:
 build/../build/common.sh:431 kube::build::build_image(...)   2:
 build/run.sh:31 main(...) Exiting with status 1
```

[image: Screen output 1]

And this one:

```
root@web3:/var/tmp/test1/kubernetes#  make release KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS=linux/386`

 +++ [1221 12:38:41] Verifying Prerequisites....
 +++ [1221 12:38:42] Building Docker image kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1
 +++ Docker build command failed for kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1

 Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.75kB Step 1/16 : FROM
 k8s.gcr.io/kube-cross:v1.13.4-1  ---> cb825830a0c3 Step 2/16 : RUN
 touch /kube-build-image  ---> Running in ae4aa5d46d3b
 standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format
 error" The command '/bin/sh -c touch /kube-build-image' returned a
 non-zero code: 1

 To retry manually, run:

 docker build -t kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1 --pull=false
 /var/tmp/test1/kubernetes/_output/images/kube-build:build-d2d69ed013-5-v1.13.4-1

 !!! [1221 12:38:46] Call tree: !!! [1221 12:38:46]  1:
 build/release.sh:35 kube::build::build_image(...) Makefile:405: recipe
 for target 'release' failed make: *** [release] Error 1
```

[image: Screen output 2]

These were tried on the following i386 machines with similar results: Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 // Centos 7 // VirtualBox with either OS (Cen/Ubu).

Any help, anyone pointing me to the right direction, it would be appreciated. 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to this address:

https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/kubernetes-master/download

Simply here, you can download a .deb file whereby you can install it, after downloading it from the closest server, in my case was CZ, depending on your location.

That is the first scenario. And I strongly recommend to download the .deb file and just click on downloaded file, the "Ubuntu Software" will open or notify you that the app is ready to be installed.

Click on Install button, enter your 'root' password, and click OK.

You can also add the http://ftp.[countrycode].... into a list in sources.d making a new text file there and adding the line:
`deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main`   for example.

For this proposes you can use the commands:

- 1. Create a text file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` naming it `kubernetes` Get the PGP key with the command `sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`
- 2. Create a text file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` naming it `kubernetes`
- 3. `$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes`
- 4. Add the line apporoprite to your location like `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main`
- 5. Then do the apt-get update and from there to install
- 6. Commands like $ sudo apt-get install -y kuberlet kubeadm kuecrl kernetes-cni

That would be it.

Comment: Thank you man. 

I'm glad that someone thought it would be useful to make 32 bit binaries (for those of us that have old computers Idling away).

And also glad that you found those binaries and gave us a hand.

In the end I was able to compile the i386 version, and it worked, but I have to rebuild the whole thing, and this time I will use your answer.

Thank you very much, your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is my experience with my VirtualBox debian 10.3.0 32bit:

added

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install kubernetes-master
```

the installation process failed in the configuration phase.

To solve I added

```
ETCD_UNSUPPORTED_ARCH=386
```

in

```
/etd/default/etcd
```

and again

```
apt-get install kubernetes-master
```

this time the installation complete with success.
Now I have the following commands available:

- kube-apiserver
- kube-controller-manager
- kubectl
- kubelet
- kube-proxy
- kube-scheduler

Now I’ve to investigate how setup a single node cluster (like minikube)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I greatly appreciate it! ^_^
I'll do some testing and see how it goes.

PS: I've voted you up, but I don't have enough reputation so the vote would be visible at this time.